# How to call inner function of jQuery-wrapper $(function() { }?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function changeGraph() inside the jQuery-wrapper which I need to call somehow from outside it. I need to access the function setData from the jQuery based graph-library Flot.

The source is looking like this:

```
function changeGraph(){
    // I need to access $.plot.setData somehow
};  

var d2 = [[0, 0], [20, 300000]];

$(function () {              
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), 
    [{color: "#000000", data: d2}],
    {

    series: {
        lines: { show: true, fill:true, fillColor: {colors: [ "#d1ddea","#8e959d"]}},
        points: { show: false }
          }
       }
    );


});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you move the function outside of the function scope?

Comment: I need to access this variable inside the scope     $.plot($("#placeholder") , I don't know to do this outside the scope

Comment: @Hedge - Can you post more of your code? I don't know why you couldn't have the `changeGraph()` in the global scope. You might consider, if you need to, using jQuery's `$.data()` to pass data into your function.

Comment: You can still use `$` if you move your function outside, like I showed in my answer.

Comment: @jtbandes - I suspect he's got other functions in that scope. The OP needs to provide more context for his problem by posting more code, I think.

Comment: I added some more context. I'm calling changeGraph() from somewhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var changeGraph;

$(function () {

    changeGraph = function () {
        // Need to access $.plot($("#placeholder") here
    };

});

changeGraph(); // call this when document is ready at least
```

Comment: This isn't really necessary.. you can access `$` from inside `changeGraph` even if you don't create it within `$(function(){...});`

Comment: @jtbandes, I don't know, maybe we don't know the full context of this particular problem. The question author asked for a way to call a function from outside jQuery closure which is defined in jQuery closure and I just showed how to do this. I don't know the details :)

Answer (score 2):

You should move your function outside of the callback function.

Comment: how do I access $.plot($("#placeholder") from inside the scope then?

Comment: @Hedge - `$.plot()` is not included in your question. You need to post more of your code (preferably everything inside your `function(){}`).

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeGraph() {
    // ...
}
$(function() {
    changeGraph();
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand this. The second changeGraph() just executes the function, doesn't it? I need to access another variable from inside the scope.

Comment: Which scope? You could use `function changeGraph() { $.plot(...); }` if you want to. This will still work.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand the wrapper `$(function() { ... });`. This just sets up a function to be executed when the document is loaded (or the DOM is ready for manipulation). You can still use `$` in other places.