# How to call a function inside a function in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jQuery.SerialScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html) so I can have a slider. In the code it has a function that looks like this:

```
var j=jQuery.noConflict();
//some code here 
jQuery(function(j)
{
    //code goes here.
    //Then I need to write a function here.
    // (like the below one or a simple JS function)

    jQuery(function()
    {
        //some stuff
    });
});
```

How can I call that function from a simple JavaScript in my web page "head" section?

Comment: I don't really get your concept here. Why would you need to call a (instantly executed) function instead of implementing working code in the top function?

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem you're having? Like, if you need help using a function in the module, or even better, describe what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you've invented a solution that isn't actually usable.

Comment: i got the answer it's well explained here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486525/how-to-call-inner-function-of-jquery-wrapper-function

Comment: @Semyazas,Juhana:may be my question is not clear to you but i found the answer you can check details here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486525/how-to-call-inner-function-of-jquery-wrapper-function

Answer (score 3):

It's a confusing question, but I'll try.

```
var j=jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(j) {
  // now do whatever you like
  // e.g.
  // j("#comments").hide();
}
```

The `noConflict()` call is there in case some other library wants to use the `$` variable. So you no longer call jQuery code with `$()` but with `j()`.
Is this what you were asking?

Comment: :your answer may be  good enough but i didn't use it so i didn't mark it as accepted,for the answer of my question you can check my own comment on my question or try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486525/how-to-call-inner-function-of-jquery-wrapper-function